# Grid.ChildrenTransitions handling

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime

i have a grid on my page:

```
<Grid x:Name="Submenu" Grid.Column="1" Background="#FF12171D">
                <Grid.ChildrenTransitions>
                    <EntranceThemeTransition/>
                </Grid.ChildrenTransitions>
            </Grid>
```

It works like a submenu and i have a list of UserControls - submenu contents.
When user selects some Menu item according User control is being loaded into Submenu grid:

```
Submenu.Children.Add(new SettingsControl());
```

I want to make not them just display but with little effect, so i found this EntranceThemeTransition and tried to use it, but code fails with:

**An exception of type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in SalesPlays.exe but was not handled in user code
WinRT information: Collection property '__implicit_items' is null. [Line: 75 Position: 26]
Additional information: The text associated with this error code could not be found.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, a control that has other `children` can apply a transition to them in the following way :

```
<Grid ... >
    <Grid.ChildrenTransitions>
         <TransitionCollection>
             <EntranceThemeTransition FromHorizontalOffset="0" FromVerticalOffset="-500"/>
         </TransitionCollection>
    </Grid.ChildrenTransitions>
</Grid>
```

Offsets were written purely for demo purpose, they can be omitted.